# Find radius of inner circle of an image in C

Tags: c, math, image-processing

I am reading image and storing its pixels in Array.and also storing the height and width of image.

I am not getting from where to start the profiling of pixels to get radius of inner circle in the image.

Here is the image [image]

I thought if i find the vertical height and horizontal height of inner circle then can average it to find the diameter then radius.

Comment: Consider boundaries, where two adjacent pixels have different colour. In each (horizontal or vertical) line you have an even number of boundaries. To find the diameter of the inner circle, consider lines with 6 boundaries ... then take the maximum of the difference between the third and fourth boundary.

Comment: the color is black, you could just check till the rgb changes to (1,1,1) then its white, meaning you are in the middle, when you hit (0,0,0) again you start counting pixels, till you hit white again. If thats the case you half your pixels and you got your radius.

Check from the half height and go through the white, use this if you want to use pure C only

Comment: @pmg and A.A. these a good aproach if input will be as image1 but wont work for image2. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Veer is the inner circle always in the center ? if yes you could still use my approach and always get the radius out of it

Comment: How much can you assume about the input? Will the input image always be as above, or will a more generalised approach be needed? If you might find the image changes, I'd be considering the use of the Hough Transform to locate all of the circles. Once this was done, it would be a trivial task to report the smallest radius of the circles found, since you'd get a location and a size for each of them. Here's a page that demonstrates the process: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/38470/how-to-detect-circles-in-images

Comment: @enhzflep this would be a really good answer if it was not a comment.

Comment: Is the circle always centred in the image?

Comment: Yeah It will at the center. @enhzflep The Houghs transform! can it be coded in C. As per your link its in python and if it is converted to C it would be large project itself. Instead a random approach would be easy.

Comment: If the inner circle is centered at the center of the image, just count black pixels from the center left (or up, or down, ...).

Comment: @pmg Exactly where I was heading with my question :-)

Comment: pmg thanks that's useful. Any other possible methods ?